# Installing Pandas - Visual C++ is required, Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, django, numpy, pandas, anaconda

I am trying to install Pandas for Python 3.4 for a Django project, however I get the error `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`.

How can I install Pandas on Python 3.4 in Windows?

Comment: Do you want to know how to set up your computer to build Pandas from source, or how to install Pandas without having to build it from source?

Comment: If the first, it's a dup of many questions here; I think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) is the canonical answer, even though it may be a bit out of date.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install Pandas, like almost every other package for Python, is with `pip`.

Many packages (including Pandas) require a compiler, and a bunch of third-party DLLs, and many Windows users don't know how to deal with that. That's exactly why the "wheel" format was created: so packages can upload pre-built binaries.

Not every project has pre-built binary wheels for Windows yet. But you can look at [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and find wheels for all of the most popular ones. Just follow the instructions on that page to download the wheel file and install it with `pip`.

But in the case of Pandas, you don't have to do that. They have wheels [on their download page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.16.0/#downloads), and uploaded to PyPI. And [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) tells you to use these. (Well, it first suggests you use Anaconda/Miniconda, but if you want a stock Python, use `pip` and the packages on PyPI.)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that different versions of Python will need different version of Visual C++. I use Python 3.4 and it worked with Visual C++ 10. Most of what I read recommended version 8, which probably works with 2.7, but didn't work with 3.4

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of doing it would be to use pip, as suggested by [abernert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert).
The command to be entered is :

pip install pandas
You will find pip in the scripts folder in your python folder. (eg. c:\python34\Scripts).
numpy will also be installed during this process.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I'll just leave [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403680/installing-pandas-using-pip-on-windows-7) here, since it is very similar.