# Installing Pandas using Pip on Windows 7

Tags: pandas, windows, pip, python-3.4

Having issues installing Pandas with Pip on Windows 7.

EDIT:
Seems like I did not have Microsoft Visual C++ installed.
The much easier approach, as someone kindly mentioned, was to install Anaconda and use it as the package manager as opposed to Python's native pip, although, for some packages (i.e [PyBullet](https://pybullet.org/wordpress/)), you might have to default back to using Pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tags I guess you are using Windows as OS. Many people use Anaconda. It comes with many packages including pandas. The line is [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) It should be easy to install. Do you use any IDE?

Comment: Not really. I have only been coding on Python for 6 months. I heard PyCharm is good and would detect such things easily. I heard of Anaconda, but I would like to fix this without using that.

Comment: I've used PyCharm too. Once you install Anaconda, you can choose it as project interpreter. It will save you a lot of time to install other packages in Python :)

Comment: ok Thank you. I have installed PyCharm, and am figuring out how to get Conda. Will inform you of the result ASAP.

Comment: No problem. If you think my answer helpful, please upvote it. Thanks!